# Triggered Emails: Welcome Journeys

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page, triggered-send

In my current setup, welcome emails are triggered when a customer makes a purchase (SOAP call from hybris), and when a customer submits a form on a landing page.

Welcome emails do not seem to work for the landing page. The workflow that is invoked by the form submit should trigger the email automatically.

Comment: Is this a landing page hosted in the Marketing Cloud? If so, keep in that products like CloudPages can't run server-side code like PHP, you would need to use AMPscript to make the call.

Comment: The landing page was created is hosted in Marketing Cloud but not a cloud page

Comment: Ah. I haven't used the Landing Pages feature in Email Studio, but I assume it has the same limitations. Maybe somebody else can confirm because I can't find a definitive answer in the documentation.

Comment: landing pages and cloud pages do have the same limitation in this regard. You can only use SSJS and AMPscript (potentially GTL as well) for server side scripting.